# Haskell Beginner, recursive function, list, Error: Non-exhaustive patterns

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

i try to write a function  [int] -> int to count the sum of a list of integers with an iterative function (result should equal the build in function sum)

```
19>sumList :: [Int] -> Int
20>sumList [list] | length[list] > 0  = [list]!!0 + sumList (drop 1 [list])
21>               | otherwise = 0
```

This is the result if i try to run it

```
uebung1.lhs:20:2: warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
In an equation for ‘sumList’:
    Patterns not matched:
        []
        (_:_:_)
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> sumList []
*** Exception: uebung1.lhs:(20,2)-(21,31): Non-exhaustive patterns in     function sumList

*Main> sumList [3]
*** Exception: uebung1.lhs:(20,2)-(21,31): Non-exhaustive patterns in   function sumListi i i i i
```

What have i done wrong? I've slept a night over it but i just dont see where the problem is. The guarded equations should catch all cases of list lengths. Thanks for any advise.

Comment: Isn't this recursive?

Comment: yes indeed fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your pattern matches only a list with one element.

For example, if you try to define a function in `ghci`:

```
a [x] = x
```

And then try to call it with the lists with a different number of elements:

`a [1]` results with `1`

`a []` results with `Exception: <interactive>:5:1-13: Non-exhaustive patterns in function a`

`a [1,2]` results with `Exception: <interactive>:1:1-9: Non-exhaustive patterns in function a`

The following modification makes your function work:

```
sumList :: [Int] -> Int
sumList list | length list > 0  = list!!0 + sumList (drop 1 list)
             | otherwise = 0
```

But, certainly, the following definition would be more idiomatic and performant:

```
sumList :: [Int] -> Int
sumList [] = 0
sumList (x:xs) = x + sumList xs
```

By `(x:xs)` pattern you immediately receive `x` as a head of your list (`list!!0`) and `xs` as a tail of it (`drop 1 list`)

Answer (score 1):

The function will not work for an empty list, or any list with more than one item.

Your problem is that you are matching against `[list]`, a list with one member which is `list`. Instead, try matching against just `list`. This means it will match anything of type `[Int]` from your type signature.

I get your confusion, as the type `[a]` is for lists of any length, but `[a]` will only match a list of one element.

I have also attached another way of writing your function using pattern matching, which hopefully you will find useful.

```
sumList :: [Int] -> Int
sumList [] = 0
sumList (x:xs) = x + sumList xs
```

It is unusual to use guards, but you did, your code would look like this:

```
sumList :: [Int] -> Int
sumList list
    | length list > 0 = head list + sumList (tail list)
    | otherwise = 0
```

Notice how `[list]` has been replaced by `list`, and `!! 0` has been replaced by `head`, and `drop 1` has been replaced by `tail`.

Hoogle is your friend!

You could also move the check for an empty list to the first guard, like so:

```
sumList :: [Int] -> Int
sumList list
    | list == [] = 0
    | otherwise = head list + sumList (tail list)
```

Note how similar this code is to the pattern matching code.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already answered, but I want to stress that the warning emitted by the compiler spotted the issue:

```
Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
In an equation for ‘sumList’:
    Patterns not matched:
        []
        (_:_:_)
```

This is saying that the code is not handling some cases in its pattern matching. The empty list `[]` above is reported as non-matched, meaning that the program will crash on the empty list. Also, the lists of the form `(_:_:_)` are not matched: these are lists having at least two elements, such as `1:2:rest` which is a list starting with elements `1` and `2` and then proceeding with list `rest` for the next elements.

So, the warning is telling us that we only handle lists of length one. Indeed, we only handle the pattern `[_]`, which is the same of `_:[]` -- a list starting with one element and then ending there.

If you are a beginner, I think you did not learn pattern matching yet. This should be your priority for learning Haskell: it is one of the most important features. Generally speaking, if your recursive code uses `length, !!, tail, head` it is very likely that your are doing it wrong. There are some places where these functions are needed, but in many simple exercises they are not, pattern matching being usually sufficient and elegant.